# Why $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}} = sin^{-1}\frac{x}{3}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't understand how the two formulas are equal since the right side involves trigonometric sine that the left is devoid of.

Comment: Try a trig substitution... choose it in such a way that $9-x^2$ becomes a perfect square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following substitution

$$ (*) \qquad x=\dfrac{3}{2}\sin t \implies \text{ d}x = \dfrac{3}{2} \cos t \text{ d}t $$

This'll yield the following equality

$$ \underbrace{\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x^2}} \text{ d}x \ \overset{(*)}= \ \dfrac{1}{3} \int \dfrac{1}{|\cos t|} \dfrac{3}{2} \cos t \text{ d}t}_{\because \ \sqrt{9-4\left(\frac{9}{4}\sin (t)\right)^2} \ = \ 3 |\cos (t)|} \ = \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2} \int \mathrm{sgn}\left(\cos(t)\right) \text{ d}t}_{\because \ \mathrm{sgn}\left(\cos(t)\right) \ \cdot \ |\cos(t)| \ =: \ \cos(t) }  = \dfrac{1}{2} \ t \ \mathrm{sgn}\left(\cos(t)\right) + \mathcal{C} $$

Finally, reverting our substitution back, we have that

$$ t = \arcsin \left( \dfrac{2x}{3} \right) $$

and that

$$ \mathrm{sgn}\left(\cos(t)\right) = \mathrm{sgn}\left( \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{2x}{3}\right)^2} \right) = +1 $$

so we finally have that

$$ \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x^2}} \text{ d}x \ = \ \dfrac{1}{2} \arcsin \left( \dfrac{2x}{3} \right) + \mathcal{C} $$

Comment: I hope my answer helped. It's bad that people overlook the absolute value of the term remaining after expressing the denominator as the square root of a perfect square. It doesn't just magically disappear in some cases, so you gotta work through it the way I have. :-)

Comment: For more reading about the [Signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), I've enclosed a link to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want to tell I didn't understand the problem because I forgot sin^-1(x) isn't 1/sinx but instead arcsinx...

Comment: Oh, gotcha! It's a common oversight. Some notation can be very confusing! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

$Hint: $

What if you put $u = 3\sin t$ ?. Will the derivative and the expression kind of cancel out and make it easy ?

Comment: Thanks! But I've edited the question to make my problem clearer. Can you also answer the current question for me?

Comment: I think Khallil has answered it. That should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general for every integral having $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ you can use the substitution $$u=a\sin x$$ and then differentiate and calculate the integral. $\sin^{-1} will& be appear.

Answer (score 0):

My process of thinking when seeing an integral like this is the following:

$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\arcsin(u)+C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, is a standard primitive. Going from this standard integral to the one given in the question isn't a big stretch really:

$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{3\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{3})^2}}=\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{3})^2}}$.

Going from this we can use a variable substitution if we want to, or (as this isn't a very difficult integral) we could just think that the primitive must be looking like this:

$k\cdot \arcsin(\frac{x}{3})+C$, where $C$ again is arbitrary, and $k$ is a constant coefficient. To find the correct value for $k$ we can differentiate:

$\frac{d}{dx}(k\cdot \arcsin(\frac{x}{3})+C)=k\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{3})^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=k\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$, so we see that if $k=1$ we get our integrand. From this we can reach the conclusion.

Comment: It's probably better to just derive it by trigonometric substitution as opposed to remembering a 'standard primitive'.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But remembering this as a standard primitive is kind of like remembering the standard derivatives for inverse trigonometric functions. Deriving it by hand is certainly good to do for practise if you're inexperienced, but if one sees integrals like these often, it can be practical to know them by heart and thereby save some time.